# POS tagger to tag only the start and end of a sentence

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Is it possible to modify the stanford POS tagger so that it only tags the start and end of a sentence and nothing else?

Has this been attempted, or completed, before? Is that code available?

What file needs to be hacked to make this happen?

Is there another tool that provides this functionality relaibly, and relaitively quickly, with good formatting?

Comment: Is the question whether the tagger can delimit the start and end of a sentence (i.e., a sentence splitter), or whether it's possible to make the tagger only tag the first and last words of a sentence? The POS tagging code does not currently allow tagging only certain words in a sentence, since the tag on each word depends on the tags of the neighboring words. But, if you tag the whole sentence, you also get the first and last words?

Comment: I want to just know what are the boundaries, i.e. where the sentence starts and where it ends, so `<sentence id="0">` and `</sentence>` and so on, and nothing else, is that possible? please excuse me if I was unclear in my original question.

Comment: You can do this with the sentence splitter. From CoreNLP, just set the annotators to "tokenize,ssplit" -- then, you should get a SentencesAnnotation on your document (`Annotation` class) that defines where your sentence boundaries are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I do use the beginPosition() of the first Part Of Speech and the endPosition() of the last part of speech of the current sentence to exactly get the start and end of teh sentence in the input text.

> Just cast the part of speech to a TaggedWord. You can then easily
>   access these properties from the getters , tag() and value().

Check out this question for more info:

[List of part of speech tags per sentence with POS Tagger Standford NPL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728347/list-of-part-of-speech-tags-per-sentence-with-pos-tagger-standford-npl-in-c-shar/29733230#29733230)

Best,
Andrew